# Formula for a point intersecting a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

In my website I'm using an image of trapezoids arranged in a pentagon shape for the main menu. These trapezoids will be scaled to fit different devices. I need a formula to calculate if a point intersects one of the trapezoids. I know the coords of the point, and the coords of each of the trapezoids. I'm no math whiz, so I have been stuck at this problem for a few weeks. Thanks in advance.

[This is the main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmUfh.png). I need to be able to figure out if the mouse is clicked in a trapezoid.

P.S. It would be best if the formula could be easily translated into JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two points $A=(A_x,A_y)$ and $B=(B_x,B_y)$, define: 
$$
A\times B=A_xB_y-A_yB_x.
$$

Given a trapezoid $ABCD$ with bases $AB$, $CD$ and legs $AD$, $BC$, a point $P$ is inside the trapezoid if both of the following inequalities are true:
$$
[(P-A)\times(B-A)]\cdot[(P-D)\times(C-D)]<0
$$
and
$$
[(P-A)\times(D-A)]\cdot[(P-B)\times(C-B)]<0.
$$
The reason is obvious to anyone knowing about vector cross product, but I think you are not interested in such details.

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but it's still a little Greek to me (even though you didn't use any Greek letters :). I don't understand how I should subtract points from each other. If you could help me with that I'll accept your answer.

Comment: $A-B=(A_x-B_x,A_y-B_y)$.